# How to check if a string containing space is alphabet or not in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have written a code in jquery to check if a word is alphabet or not. But I want to write the code for checking a string which contains space also.

```
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(!(name.match(letters))){

    var msg = "Enter a valid name !!!";
    document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = msg;
    event.preventDefault();   

    }
```

for the input field :

```
  <input type="text" name="name" id="namee" placeholder="Full Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" required>
```

When i am inputing a name having two words, the message valid name is showing becos the space character is read as a invalid character. Can anyone suggest how to correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the regex

```
/^[A-Za-z ]+$/
```

or

```
/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex could look like following:

```
[A-Za-z\s]+
```

So it will be:

```
var letters = /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/;
```

In this case `\s` means space.

**Manual**

More about `\s` you can read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp)